# How to reference a member of a module in its parent scope, from a module?

Tags: module, rust

This simple example works in `main.rs`

```
pub mod types {
    pub struct Foo {
        _var: usize,
    }
}
use types::Foo;

fn main() {
    let _unused: Foo;
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

However, when its compiled in a file which is its self a module, this gives an error:

`` error: unresolved import `types::Foo`. Maybe a missing `extern crate types`? ``

Is it possible to make a reference to a submodule's public member, from a module?

Answer (score 3):

When in a module, `self` needs to be used, eg:

```
pub mod types {
    pub struct Foo {
        _var: usize,
    }
}
use self::types::Foo;  // <-- self here
```

---

*Thanks to @nox on IRC for this answer.*